# The bar has been raised

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I have two directors, but no actors.
>
> I have three numbers, but no equations.
>
> I have two letters, but no packages.
>
> I have nine dots, but no vectors.
>
> I have fifteen lines, but no content.
>
> I have two links, but no zeldas.
>
> I have two arrows, but no bow.
>
> I have one quote, but no source.
>
> I have one picture, but no artist.
>
> I have one more thing yet to be described.
>
> What is it? What description has overlapped?
>
> And more importantly, what am *I*?

Hint:

> It appears that the first clue was the trickiest. The director mentioned is an actual movie director, but this clue is kind of......for the *birds*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are

> the answer box!

which looks like this :

> [image]

and corresponds to all the clues :

```
I have two directors, but no actors.
```

> Preformatted text represent two brackets, which are similar to Hitchcock's silhouette (@Arnaud)

```
I have three numbers, but no equations.
```

> 123 in Numbered list

```
I have two letters, but no packages.
```

> Bold and italic

```
I have nine dots, but no vectors.
```

> 3 from Bullet List 5 from Horizontal Rule and (@Arnaud) 1 from the Picture icon

```
I have fifteen lines, but no content.
```

> All lines from Numbered List, Bullet List, Heading and Horizontal Rule

```
I have two links, but no zeldas.
```

> Links of the hyperlink icon

```
I have two arrows, but no bow.
```

> Undo and redo

```
I have one quote, but no source.
```

> Quote icon

```
I have one picture, but no artist.
```

> Picture icon

```
I have one more thing yet to be described. What is it?
```

> The help icon (which actually adds a seventh dot)

```
What description has overlapped?
```

> Picture icon is described twice (@Arnaud)

Comment: Also... (r13) Zl nafjre obk abj unf pbagrag... Fb ol nafjrevat guvf, vf gur nafjre jebat ? Hafbyinoyr chmmyr !

Comment: Very nice! You are definitely on the right track. You miscounted one element, which will help explain the last line. The first line refers to a certain director - I can name him in a hint if you don't figure it out in a while. Preformatted Text is the object referenced. Also, no, it wasn't supposed to be unsolvable lol.

Comment: The directors and the arrows might be referring to the same things.  Arrows give directions, after all.

Comment: Vg'f abg 6 qbgf va gur qbggrq yvar, vg'f bayl 5. Gur ynfg bar pbzrf sebz gur cvpgher. Naq gurersber vf cneg bs gur bireync.

Comment: What about the title?

Comment: @noedne the answer was technically supposed to be the answer menu "bar", but I didn't feel like being that picky.

Comment: Good one - reminds me of my first puzzle I created here:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71996/a-spell-for-summoning-help

Comment: Gur avar qbgf zvtug ersre gb gur qbgf ba gur obggbz rqtr bs gur nafjre obk hfrq gb erfvmr gur obk.

Comment: Yay, you're almost there! I've added a hint for that first clue.

Comment: So with the hint and what's missing... rot13(gur pheyl oenpxrgf xvaq bs erfrzoyr nyserq uvgpupbpx'f fvyubhrggr sebz uvf gi fubj vageb). Slightly farfetched but would fit.

Comment: @NudgeNudge it is a little far-fetched, but it is also correct. I've known rot13(fbzr crbcyr gb pnyy pheyl oenprf "Uvgpupbpxf" orpnhfr bs guvf.)

Comment: OK, the clue gave it away, but I would never have found why it was that specific director in a million years (never heard of the expression you mention, Brandon). I've edited my answer with credits to Arnaud, and I ethink everything is correct now !

Comment: It is! Congratulations. Sorry about the abstract director clue.

Comment: Ahahaha! Great answer and great puzzle! This is really funny :)

Comment: @North thanks. Kind of funny knowing that everyone who started to attempt this puzzle was looking at the answer the whole time. :)